# cant compare two strings with equals() in java

Tags: java, android

Im sorry, please help...

as you can see in console.. my variable description and my variable kabupaten is same, but equals return is false...

Thanks for your help. [Link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfTYc.png)

```
public class XMLParsingTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {
private String kabupaten;
 String description = xmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(null, "description");
                System.out.println("Description = " + description);
                System.out.println("Kabupaten = " + kabupaten);
                System.out.println(description.equals(kabupaten));
                System.out.println(description);
                System.out.println(kabupaten);
```

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Comment: There may be invisible characters.

Comment: I don't see you trying to compare those variables

Comment: System.out.println(description.equals(kabupaten)); sorry sir, i compare in this

Comment: have you checked for invisible chars?

Comment: Owh Ok thanks i will try find out

Comment: Start by printing things like `"Description = <" + description +">")` to ensure you get such details. And if that doesnt help, write code that fetches char by char from both strings and prints the first mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.. Yes, there is space in one of my variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have space in them.

```
String description = description.trim();
System.out.println(description.equals(kabupaten.trim));
```

Comment: Thanks Sir.... Very Appreciate